# Disable the 'see though mode' in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am currently modeling an ear and it becomes very hard to see some vertices

[image]

I know that I could hide some geometry in the background, but is it possible to completely disable the see though mode so that I only see the vertices on the surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable limit selection to visible in the bottom tool bar.

[image]